# How does Elliott start feeling/behaving like E.T.?

Tags: plot-explanation, et-the-extra-terrestrial

In E.T. when Elliott is at school and E.T. is alone at home with the dog, strange things start happening. When E.T. drinks beer, Elliott starts feeling dizzy.
When E.T. watches a romantic scene on TV, Elliott kisses his classmate to whom he wasn't paying much attention earlier. What's the explanation for this sequence?

Comment: It's a psychic connection which is one of ET's alien powers. It's why Elliott gets sick later when ET does. I'm not sure what else to write in the answer, really, which is why it's a comment. ;) (This is touched upon in [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7271/why-do-e-t-and-elliott-get-sick-and-how-do-they-recover) over at Sci-Fi.)

Comment: I think the question is **when** or **why** that connection happens, and why doesn't it happen to anyone else?  Didn't ET save/revive Elliott at some point?  It's been years since I've seen it.

Comment: Empathy as in telepathy. Duh

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Director Steven Spielberg describes the bond between E.T and Eliot as a "double rescue".

Spielberg explains how he desired a friend like E.T. that he could share a special bond with after his parents divorce.  He goes on to explain that Eliot has a need that E.T. can fulfill and E.T. has a need that Eliot can fulfill.

The explanation is that they share such a tight bond that they adhere to one another's physical and emotional state.

The interview with Steven Spielberg from [AFI](https://youtu.be/aiqLxSuXBzI)

Answer (score 2):

Eliot and E.T. have a deep connection. Deeper than friendship. They have become one. They feel and think the same. E.T. wants to go home and his only chance is through Eliot. He therefore creates a special bond between them. Everything E.T. feels, Eliot does. It also shows to the audience the inseparable relationship between boy and alien.

Answer (score 1):

The moment E.T. touched his glowing fingertip to the cut on Eliot's finger, which he got from mishandling the buzz-saw blade among the items collected to help E.T. build his S.O.S. beacon, the two were bonded physically & psychically.